# Determine the magnitude and direction of the net electric field at P

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

I can't seem to understand this question, I can get the electric force between the charges using distance a but don't understand what I should do after that.

> The electric field is a vector and so two electric fields at the same point in space must be added according to the laws of vector addition. Consider two equal positive charges q, each 2.00 μC, separated by a=10.0cm and a point P a distance of d = 30.0 cm, as shown in the diagram.The diagram shows the directions of the electric fields produced at P by each charge. Determine the magnitude and direction of the net electric field at P.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy. Take the semi-vertical angle of the triangle so formed as $\theta$ such that $\tan {\theta}=\frac{a/2}{d}$. Then, resolve each of the electric fields along the horizontal and vertical directions. Evidently, the magnitudes of the two electric fields (shown in green in your diagram) are equal due to the geometry of the problem and so their vertical components cancel each other and their horizontal components (along the height of the triangle) add together.

Let, $E$ be the magnitude of both of the electric fields. So the magnitude of the net electric field at $P$ becomes
$$E_{net}=2E\cos {\theta}=2E\displaystyle{\frac{d}{\sqrt {{(a/2)}^2+d^2}}}$$ and its direction is rightwards from $P$.